# Unable to send email from CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am using CodeIgniter v3.1.4.In my website i have a 'Contact Us' page whose email sending function is not working at all.The strangest thing is that the exact code is working perfectly in one of my another project while its not in this project.

```
$this->email->send()
```

The above line executes but it does not send any emails.Neither does it show any error messages.However, if 'from' address & 'to' address are the same like(info@mywebsite.org) then it does send mail to itself.When 'from' address is like (user@gmail.com) and 'to' address is like (info@mywebsite.org), it does not work.

The code that i am using to send email is:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sender_name', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sender_email', 'Enter Email', 'required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail_subject', 'Subject', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail_message', 'Your Message', 'required');

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $this->email->from($this->input->post('sender_email'), $this->input->post('sender_name'));
        $this->email->to("info@mywebsite.org");
        $this->email->subject($this->input->post('mail_subject'));
        $this->email->message($this->input->post('mail_message'));

        if($this->email->send()){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Thanks for writing to us.You would hear from us shortly.');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Your message could not be sent.');
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to implement other solutions here in StackOverflow, but none of them are working.Please help me.

Comment: what error you got

Comment: i don't get any errors

Comment: Your logic here is flawed. Your whole user experience hinges on your ability to send email. What you should do is make an email queue in your database, and mark each freshly inserted email as unsent. Then use a cron to send the email, and mark it as sent if successful.

Comment: `$this->email->print_debugger(); ` try to print this display what misstake you did

Comment: @vijay, $this->email->print_debugger();  not printing anything :(

Comment: @gomeshmunda `$this->email->send()` use after that `print_r($this->email->print_debugger())` it will display error sure if email steup wrong, otherwise it will print successfully sent

Comment: @vijay, did as you suggested and again it shows nothing at all, not even a dot

Comment: @gomeshmunda  did you load email libtary

Comment: yep sure, inside the constructor like $this->load->library('email');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154195/discussion-between-vijay-sharma-and-gomesh-munda).

Answer (score 0):

First Check With static data

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
echo "<pre>status<br>"print_r($this->email->print_debugger());die;
```